# Android Google Map Addon not available?

Tags: android, eclipse

i am trying to display google map on Android refering to this tutorial
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html
when i go to google website to download addon it says addons are not available kindly guide what should i do to achieve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the Add-on page more carefully you'll see this:

> The Google APIs add-on is not yet available for download. For your convenience, the Google APIs add-on is available preinstalled in the Android SDK.

So you should already have the Google APIs add-on already if you've installed the Android SDK.

To check, run the `android` command with no options at a command prompt to open the **Android SDK and AVD Manager** GUI.  Check **Installed Packages** to confirm that Google APIs is listed:

[image]

If it's not listed use the **Available Packages** option to install it.

If you're using Eclipse, you also need to [edit the Properties of your Project and select the correct Build Target](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html):

[image]

Comment: ok thanks for reply could you please guide one more thing there are several related to google which to choose for example i can see in the list google api by google inc , 
android api3, revision 3 ,
google api by google inc , 
android api4 revision 2, google api by google inc  android api5 revision 1 ,
google api by google inc  android api6 revision 1,
google api by google inc  android api7 revision 1

Comment: You'll need to use the one which matches the level for your application.  Or more specifically, the one which matches the `android:minSdkVersion` attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: ok thanks for reply in minsdkversion written 6 and i have downloaded 7 is there any problem if i use this one???

Comment: Yes, this will be a problem.  minSdkVersion = 6 means your application is supported on Android 2.0.1 and above; the Google APIs you've downloaded are only supported on 2.1 and above.

Comment: i have installed google apis by google inc. android api 7,revision 1
and restarted eclipse but still i am getting error on importing name space
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

Comment: let me try doing api6 revision 1

Comment: STill no hope... i cannot get com.google it is still giving me error any other solution or something i might be missing could you please guide me??

Comment: The Documents also says that you need to update your **Build Target**.  Have you done this?  I've added this to the answer above.

Comment: when i saw that option it was already selected.....but still not able to access that com.google and its inner classes.. :(

Comment: finally its working now thanks for support dave a restart of eclipse was required to do this..